# Retrieve the object id from sys.sysobjects in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008

How to retrieve the object id from sys.sysobjects table using table name and column name in MS sql server?

Answer (score 1):

I think you you are looking for this-

```
USE [DatabaseName]
SELECT OBJECT_ID(N'[SchemaName].[ObjectName]',N'ObjectType')
```

If you are trying to find out a table's object id, then try with this--

```
USE [DatabaseName]
SELECT OBJECT_ID(N'[SchemaName].[TableName]',N'TT')
```

For more about `OBJECT_ID()` [go here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190328.aspx) and to find out `Object Type` [go here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190324.aspx)